# Progress bar with float value

Tags: jquery

I am working on the circliful plugin but I want to include float values as well and this plugin works for only integer values.
Any idea how I can work for float values?

```js
$(function() {
 $('#progress').circliful();
});


//Note -- I removed the respondCanvas function from the circiful library
/* PROGRESS CIRCLE COMPONENT */
(function ($) {

    $.fn.circliful = function (options, callback) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            startdegree: 0,
            fgcolor: "#556b2f",
            bgcolor: "#eee",
            fill: false,
            width: 15,
            dimension: 200,
            fontsize: 15,
            percent: 50,
            animationstep: 1.0,
            iconsize: '20px',
            iconcolor: '#999',
            border: 'default',
            complete: null,
            bordersize: 10
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            var customSettings = ["fgcolor", "bgcolor", "fill", "width", "dimension", "fontsize", "animationstep", "endPercent", "icon", "iconcolor", "iconsize", "border", "startdegree", "bordersize"];

            var customSettingsObj = {};
            var icon = '';
            var endPercent = 0;
            var obj = $(this);
            var fill = false;
            var text, info;

            obj.addClass('circliful');

            checkDataAttributes(obj);

            if (obj.data('text') != undefined) {
                text = obj.data('text');

                if (obj.data('icon') != undefined) {
                    icon = $('<i></i>')
                        .addClass('fa ' + $(this).data('icon'))
                        .css({
                            'color': customSettingsObj.iconcolor,
                            'font-size': customSettingsObj.iconsize
                        });
                }

                if (obj.data('type') != undefined) {
                    type = $(this).data('type');

                    if (type == 'half') {
                        addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text-half', (customSettingsObj.dimension / 1.45));
                    } else {
                        addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text', customSettingsObj.dimension);
                    }
                } else {
                    addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text', customSettingsObj.dimension);
                }
            }

            if ($(this).data("total") != undefined && $(this).data("part") != undefined) {
                var total = $(this).data("total") / 100;

                percent = (($(this).data("part") / total) / 100).toFixed(3);
                endPercent = ($(this).data("part") / total).toFixed(3)
            } else {
                if ($(this).data("percent") != undefined) {
                    percent = $(this).data("percent") / 100;
                    endPercent = $(this).data("percent")
                } else {
                    percent = settings.percent / 100
                }
            }

            if ($(this).data('info') != undefined) {
                info = $(this).data('info');

                if ($(this).data('type') != undefined) {
                    type = $(this).data('type');

                    if (type == 'half') {
                        addInfoText(obj, 0.9);
                    } else {
                        addInfoText(obj, 1.25);
                    }
                } else {
                    addInfoText(obj, 1.25);
                }
            }

            $(this).width(customSettingsObj.dimension + 'px');

            var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>').attr({
                width: customSettingsObj.dimension,
                height: customSettingsObj.dimension
            }).appendTo($(this)).get(0);

            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var container = $(canvas).parent();
            var x = canvas.width / 2;
            var y = canvas.height / 2;
            var degrees = customSettingsObj.percent * 360.0;
            var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
            var radius = canvas.width / 2.5;
            var startAngle = 2.3 * Math.PI;
            var endAngle = 0;
            var counterClockwise = false;
            var curPerc = customSettingsObj.animationstep === 0.0 ? endPercent : 0.0;
            var curStep = Math.max(customSettingsObj.animationstep, 0.0);
            var circ = Math.PI * 2;
            var quart = Math.PI / 2;
            var type = '';
            var fireCallback = true;
            var additionalAngelPI = (customSettingsObj.startdegree / 180) * Math.PI;

            if ($(this).data('type') != undefined) {
                type = $(this).data('type');

                if (type == 'half') {
                    startAngle = 2.0 * Math.PI;
                    endAngle = 3.13;
                    circ = Math.PI;
                    quart = Math.PI / 0.996;
                }
            }
          
            /**
             * adds text to circle
             *
             * @param obj
             * @param cssClass
             * @param lineHeight
             */
            function addCircleText(obj, cssClass, lineHeight) {
                $("<span></span>")
                    .appendTo(obj)
                    .addClass(cssClass)
                    .text(text)
                    .prepend(icon)
                    .css({
                        'line-height': lineHeight + 'px',
                        'font-size': customSettingsObj.fontsize + 'px'
                    });
            }

            /**
             * adds info text to circle
             *
             * @param obj
             * @param factor
             */
            function addInfoText(obj, factor) {
                $('<span></span>')
                    .appendTo(obj)
                    .addClass('circle-info-half')
                    .css(
                        'line-height', (customSettingsObj.dimension * factor) + 'px'
                    )
                    .text(info);
            }

            /**
             * checks which data attributes are defined
             * @param obj
             */
            function checkDataAttributes(obj) {
                $.each(customSettings, function (index, attribute) {
                    if (obj.data(attribute) != undefined) {
                        customSettingsObj[attribute] = obj.data(attribute);
                    } else {
                        customSettingsObj[attribute] = $(settings).attr(attribute);
                    }

                    if (attribute == 'fill' && obj.data('fill') != undefined) {
                        fill = true;
                    }
                });
            }

            /**
             * animate foreground circle
             * @param current
             */
            function animate(current) {

                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(x, y, radius, endAngle, startAngle, false);

                context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.bordersize + 1;

                context.strokeStyle = customSettingsObj.bgcolor;
                context.stroke();

                if (fill) {
                    context.fillStyle = customSettingsObj.fill;
                    context.fill();
                }

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(x, y, radius, -(quart) + additionalAngelPI, ((circ) * current) - quart + additionalAngelPI, false);

                if (customSettingsObj.border == 'outline') {
                    context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.width + 13;
                } else if (customSettingsObj.border == 'inline') {
                    context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.width - 13;
                }

                context.strokeStyle = customSettingsObj.fgcolor;
                context.stroke();

                if (curPerc < endPercent) {
                    curPerc += curStep;
                    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                        animate(Math.min(curPerc, endPercent) / 100);
                    }, obj);
                }

                if (curPerc == endPercent && fireCallback && typeof(options) != "undefined") {
                    if ($.isFunction(options.complete)) {
                        options.complete();

                        fireCallback = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            animate(curPerc / 100);

        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
/* DEMO STYLES */
body {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: #db3a3d;
  text-align:center;
}


/* PROGRESS CIRCLE COMPONENT */
.circliful {
    margin:auto;
    position: relative; 
}

.circle-text, .circle-info, .circle-text-half, .circle-info-half {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.circle-info, .circle-info-half {
 color: #999;
}

.circliful .fa {
 margin: -10px 3px 0 3px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well" style="background: #fff;">
  <h2>Progress Circle</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="progress" data-dimension="200" data-text="65%" data-fontsize="36" data-percent="65" data-fgcolor="#30B455" data-bgcolor="#eee" data-width="15" data-bordersize="15" data-animationstep="2"></div>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful" target="_blank">
      Circliful Docs <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/jacobhummel/pen/kyugL

Comment: The plugin code on which I am working

Comment: Looks fine to me. What do you mean it 'works for integers but not floats'?

Comment: Apparently there's a commit that include decimals... https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful/pull/100. Maybe you can get that or apply it to your plugin version

Comment: it is an open issue https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful/issues/96

Comment: Works fine in the pen.

Comment: @aashimavinayak you have to wait until they resolve the open issue.

Comment: @aashimavinayak  i have modified your code little bit. let me know weather it is working as per your requirement or not

Comment: thanks everyone, it's working now.@DhavalPankhaniya thank you so much

Comment: your welcome @aashimavinayak :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me know if it is working for you

```js
$(function() {
 $('#progress').circliful();
});


//Note -- I removed the respondCanvas function from the circiful library
/* PROGRESS CIRCLE COMPONENT */
(function ($) {

    $.fn.circliful = function (options, callback) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            startdegree: 0,
            fgcolor: "#556b2f",
            bgcolor: "#eee",
            fill: false,
            width: 15,
            dimension: 200,
            fontsize: 15,
            percent: 50,
            animationstep: 1.0,
            iconsize: '20px',
            iconcolor: '#999',
            border: 'default',
            complete: null,
            bordersize: 10
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            var customSettings = ["fgcolor", "bgcolor", "fill", "width", "dimension", "fontsize", "animationstep", "endPercent", "icon", "iconcolor", "iconsize", "border", "startdegree", "bordersize"];

            var customSettingsObj = {};
            var icon = '';
            var endPercent = 0;
            var obj = $(this);
            var fill = false;
            var text, info;

            obj.addClass('circliful');

            checkDataAttributes(obj);

            if (obj.data('text') != undefined) {
                text = obj.data('text');

                if (obj.data('icon') != undefined) {
                    icon = $('<i></i>')
                        .addClass('fa ' + $(this).data('icon'))
                        .css({
                            'color': customSettingsObj.iconcolor,
                            'font-size': customSettingsObj.iconsize
                        });
                }

                if (obj.data('type') != undefined) {
                    type = $(this).data('type');

                    if (type == 'half') {
                        addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text-half', (customSettingsObj.dimension / 1.45));
                    } else {
                        addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text', customSettingsObj.dimension);
                    }
                } else {
                    addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text', customSettingsObj.dimension);
                }
            }

            if ($(this).data("total") != undefined && $(this).data("part") != undefined) {
                var total = $(this).data("total") / parseFloat(100);

                percent = (($(this).data("part") / total) / parseFloat(100)).toFixed(3);
                endPercent = ($(this).data("part") / total).toFixed(3)
            } else {
                if ($(this).data("percent") != undefined) {
                    percent = $(this).data("percent") / parseFloat(100);
                    endPercent = $(this).data("percent")
                } else {
                    percent = settings.percent / parseFloat(100)
                }
            }

            if ($(this).data('info') != undefined) {
                info = $(this).data('info');

                if ($(this).data('type') != undefined) {
                    type = $(this).data('type');

                    if (type == 'half') {
                        addInfoText(obj, 0.9);
                    } else {
                        addInfoText(obj, 1.25);
                    }
                } else {
                    addInfoText(obj, 1.25);
                }
            }

            $(this).width(customSettingsObj.dimension + 'px');

            var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>').attr({
                width: customSettingsObj.dimension,
                height: customSettingsObj.dimension
            }).appendTo($(this)).get(0);

            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var container = $(canvas).parent();
            var x = canvas.width / 2;
            var y = canvas.height / 2;
            var degrees = customSettingsObj.percent * 360.0;
            var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
            var radius = canvas.width / 2.5;
            var startAngle = 2.3 * Math.PI;
            var endAngle = 0;
            var counterClockwise = false;
            var curPerc = customSettingsObj.animationstep === 0.0 ? endPercent : 0.0;
            var curStep = Math.max(customSettingsObj.animationstep, 0.0);
            var circ = Math.PI * 2;
            var quart = Math.PI / 2;
            var type = '';
            var fireCallback = true;
            var additionalAngelPI = (customSettingsObj.startdegree / 180) * Math.PI;

            if ($(this).data('type') != undefined) {
                type = $(this).data('type');

                if (type == 'half') {
                    startAngle = 2.0 * Math.PI;
                    endAngle = 3.13;
                    circ = Math.PI;
                    quart = Math.PI / 0.996;
                }
            }
          
            /**
             * adds text to circle
             *
             * @param obj
             * @param cssClass
             * @param lineHeight
             */
            function addCircleText(obj, cssClass, lineHeight) {
                $("<span></span>")
                    .appendTo(obj)
                    .addClass(cssClass)
                    .text(text)
                    .prepend(icon)
                    .css({
                        'line-height': lineHeight + 'px',
                        'font-size': customSettingsObj.fontsize + 'px'
                    });
            }

            /**
             * adds info text to circle
             *
             * @param obj
             * @param factor
             */
            function addInfoText(obj, factor) {
                $('<span></span>')
                    .appendTo(obj)
                    .addClass('circle-info-half')
                    .css(
                        'line-height', (customSettingsObj.dimension * factor) + 'px'
                    )
                    .text(info);
            }

            /**
             * checks which data attributes are defined
             * @param obj
             */
            function checkDataAttributes(obj) {
                $.each(customSettings, function (index, attribute) {
                    if (obj.data(attribute) != undefined) {
                        customSettingsObj[attribute] = obj.data(attribute);
                    } else {
                        customSettingsObj[attribute] = $(settings).attr(attribute);
                    }

                    if (attribute == 'fill' && obj.data('fill') != undefined) {
                        fill = true;
                    }
                });
            }

            /**
             * animate foreground circle
             * @param current
             */
            function animate(current) {

                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(x, y, radius, endAngle, startAngle, false);

                context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.bordersize + 1;

                context.strokeStyle = customSettingsObj.bgcolor;
                context.stroke();

                if (fill) {
                    context.fillStyle = customSettingsObj.fill;
                    context.fill();
                }

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(x, y, radius, -(quart) + additionalAngelPI, ((circ) * current) - quart + additionalAngelPI, false);

                if (customSettingsObj.border == 'outline') {
                    context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.width + 13;
                } else if (customSettingsObj.border == 'inline') {
                    context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.width - 13;
                }

                context.strokeStyle = customSettingsObj.fgcolor;
                context.stroke();

                if (curPerc < endPercent) {
                    curPerc += curStep;
                    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                        animate(Math.min(curPerc, endPercent) / parseFloat(100));
                    }, obj);
                }

                if (curPerc == endPercent && fireCallback && typeof(options) != "undefined") {
                    if ($.isFunction(options.complete)) {
                        options.complete();

                        fireCallback = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            animate(curPerc / parseFloat(100));

        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
/* DEMO STYLES */
body {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: #db3a3d;
  text-align:center;
}


/* PROGRESS CIRCLE COMPONENT */
.circliful {
    margin:auto;
    position: relative; 
}

.circle-text, .circle-info, .circle-text-half, .circle-info-half {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.circle-info, .circle-info-half {
 color: #999;
}

.circliful .fa {
 margin: -10px 3px 0 3px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well" style="background: #fff;">
  <h2>Progress Circle</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="progress" data-dimension="200" data-text="65.5%" data-fontsize="36" data-percent="65.5" data-fgcolor="#30B455" data-bgcolor="#eee" data-width="15" data-bordersize="15" data-animationstep="2"></div>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful" target="_blank">
      Circliful Docs <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```